# Changing the LaTeX Affection text in the bottom right of a tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter, footer

In tikzposter, there's a default footnote in the bottom right that has the LaTeX and Tikzposter logos.

You can suppress the text with the command \tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

What I was wondering is if the text can be changed. I want to put a revision and date on the bottom of the poster in exactly that location, so it seemed like an easy (ish) way to do it.

Alternatively, I could just suppress it with the above command. In that case, is there a command for adding a footnote.

Note, that this isn't a normal LaTeX footnote where it is numbered and attached to some text in the document. It's just a small bit of free text.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[portrait]{tikzposter}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This produces a blank page apart from some writing in the bottom right:

[image: Blank page]

The bottom right text can be suppressed with

```
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
```

That text is exactly what I'm looking to edit though. So either suppressing and adding or editing, whichever is easier.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The affection note itself cannot easily be customized and reused, but you can switch it off and adapt its code for your purpose. In the preamble, include the following lines:

```
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{backgroundlayer}
        \node[
            inner sep=4pt, anchor=south east, fill=white, draw=none,
            rounded corners=5, fill opacity=0.3, text opacity=1
        ] at (0.5\textwidth-7pt, -0.5\textheight+7pt)
        {\footnotesize {My personal footnote}};  %%% ADAPT FOOTNOTE HERE
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}
```

This prints `My personal footnote` in the lower right corner.

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\title{Title}
\author{T.H.E.Author}
\usetheme{Basic}
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{backgroundlayer}
        \node[
            inner sep=4pt, anchor=south east, fill=white, draw=none,
            rounded corners=5, fill opacity=0.3, text opacity=1
        ] at (0.5\textwidth-7pt, -0.5\textheight+7pt)
        {\footnotesize {My personal footnote}};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
\column{0.7}
\block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
\note{Notetext}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.